# What setup.py command will update the source in site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have run

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar,zip bdist_wheel
```

and then

```
python setup.py install
```

The result is that the `egg` files are created in the `site-packages` directory but *not* the `<package-name>/<package-source files>`:

```
$ls  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infix*
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy-0.0.3-py3.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy.egg-link
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy-0.0.4-py3.7.egg
```

Notice that the directory `infix` was *not* created - and thus none of the source code was copied.   What am I missing /  not understanding in this local installation process?

**Update**  When I had run

```
  pip3 install infixpy
```

there was an additional directory `infix` and the source code was included in that directory.  Running the `local` or `devel` modes of `setup.py install` was not causing that code to be updated and - crucially - the *stacktraces* from running any python code (even in a completely new `ipython` repl) was showing only the older / `pip3` installed code.  In particular the file `__init__.py` So my observation has been that the source file :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy/__init__.py
```

is an accurate reflection of what the `python` executable were using.   @phd is mentioning that the source code is already included in the `egg`.   So then I do not understand the relationship between the source code in the `egg` and the source code in that subdirectory - which in the lastest run of mine is completely missing.

Comment: The source code is inside that `.egg` (the file is actually just a `.zip` file so you can explore it). It is automatically added to Python import path so you can import modules from it. Do you need something else?

Comment: @phd  Thx for responding and providing that insight: I will add details to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands all yield slightly different results:

- `pip install .`: installed as uncompressed package directories and a `XXX.dist-info` directory
- `pip install infixpy`: same as previous, but installed from an (remote) index (per default [PyPI](https://pypi.org)), not from the local directory
- `python setup.py install`: installed as a zipped file `XXX.egg`
- `pip install --editable .` or `python setup.py develop`: not installed, but linked as a `XXX.egg-link` file

So depending on the commands entered, the content of `site-packages` is different.

Now this is what you say you have:

> ````
> $ls  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infix*
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy-0.0.3-py3.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy.egg-link
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/infixpy-0.0.4-py3.7.egg```
> ````

This is a bit surprising, since theoretically there are 3 versions of your project that are importable (`0.0.3`, `0.0.4`, and *develop*/*editable*). I am not sure which one is used by the Python interpreter in this case. You might want to run `pip uninstall infixpy` a couple of times to start fresh and alleviate these uncertainties. You can then experiment with the commands mentioned above and see how they impact the content of `site-packages` along with inspecting the result of `pip show infixpy`.

Comment: excellent explanation: will do the uninstall and try out your suggestions